# DMA in EVE board 3

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to do DMA in eve3-43inch LCD TFT ( matrix orbital), TFT screen working without DMA but as soon I add DMA settings DMA does not respond ing. What might be the reason? I using EVE81.h library. These codes I have added to make SPI initialization with DMA.

```
void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(hspi->Instance==SPI1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**SPI1 GPIO Configuration
    PA5     ------> SPI1_SCK
    PA6     ------> SPI1_MISO
    PB5     ------> SPI1_MOSI
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* SPI1 DMA Init */
     /* SPI1_RX Init */
     hdma_spi1_rx.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_3;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
     hdma_spi1_rx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
     if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi1_rx) != HAL_OK)
     {
       Error_Handler();
     }

     __HAL_LINKDMA(hspi,hdmarx,hdma_spi1_rx);

     /* SPI1_TX Init */
     hdma_spi1_tx.Instance = DMA2_Stream3;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_3;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;  //DMA_NORMAL;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
     hdma_spi1_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_ENABLE;//DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
     if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi1_tx) != HAL_OK)
     {
       Error_Handler();
     }

     __HAL_LINKDMA(hspi,hdmatx,hdma_spi1_tx);


    /* SPI1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

Here I am transmitting as DMA or normal way. These codes working without DMA. After making it to transmit or receive through DMA LCD not responding.

```
void HAL_SPI_WriteBuffer(uint8_t *Buffer, uint32_t Length)
{
    HAL_SPI_Enable();
    volatile int result = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, Buffer, Length, 1000);
    //volatile int result = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, Buffer, Length);

    HAL_SPI_Disable();
}

void HAL_SPI_ReadBuffer(uint8_t *Buffer, uint32_t Length)
{
    //EVE requires one dummy read/write before actual data can be read 
    Buffer[0] = 0;
    volatile int result = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, Buffer, 1, 1000);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, Buffer, Length,1000);
    //volatile int result = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, Buffer, 1);
    //HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1, Buffer, Length);

}

uint8_t HAL_SPI_Write(uint8_t data)
{
    //volatile int result = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &data, 1, 1000);
    volatile int result = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, &data, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DMA operations are asynchronous. So the SPI-DMA calls start the SPI transfer and return immediately without waiting for it to complete. Therefore, you cannot immediately call another SPI function let alone `HAL_SPI_Disable()`. Instead, you have to implement the callback function and change the program such that the next SPI operation isn't started before the callback has occurred.

Comment: void HAL_SPI_TxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
  if(hspi ->Instance == SPI1)
  {
   txspi++;
  }
}

Comment: added callback function but still its not working

Comment: Due to the asynchronous operations, considerable changes to the code are required. Add the completion handler is just a small part of it. Despite their names, `HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA ` and `HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA` do not transmit or receive data. They just start the transmission and reception, respectively. Therefore, it's not possible to call these functions one after the other. Read up on how DMA and asynchronous actions work.